# How do I query tables from a Big5 Jet Database on Windows 7 en-US from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, jet, big5

I've got a really old Big5 Jet Database that I would like to convert to Unicode and SQLite.

The first step here is to actually open the jet database. Using the C# ADO, and I can enumerate the tables in the Jet DB. They are all garbled, which is expected to me on Windows 7 en-US.

Now, if I simply take those table names and throw them into a simple

```
   select * from "[garbled text]"
```

the jet database complains how it can't find the table. Similarly, if I attempt to load the jet database into Microsoft Access 2010, it is able to see tables but not query from them.

After hammering on this for a while, I decide to fire up the original host of the database, Windows XP zh-tw, which has Big5/Code Page 950 support.

I throw the exact same failing binary from Windows 7 zh-tw into Windows XP zh-tw. I run the exe and boom, it's able to query the tables no problem.

**I'd really like to be able to do this on Windows 7 and I'd also really like to do this without depending on the host culture.**

Things I've tried but failed:

- Changing the thread culture to zh-tw of the thread that instantiates the jet db objects.
- Specifying a locale on the ADO Source string:

  ```
  Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Locale Identifier=950;
  ```

  The jet database also has its own threadpool, but I don't know how to get to those threads to change their culture.

**Is there anything I can do to query tables from this database on Windows 7 en-US?**

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 (any language), you can change system locale:

- Region and Language -> Administrative -> Change system locale -> Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan) -> Ok, reboot

I don't know how to change Jet/ADO.NET locale in code, sorry.

Comment: This has no relevance to the question. Moreover, it ignores the requirement that the program be independent from system culture/locale.